# How to define fewer slides on smaller devices

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I use a `slick carousel` which is initiated like this:

```
$('.client-carousel').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  arrows: false,
  slide: 'li'
});
```

Now I want to achieve that on an iPhone 6 for example, which has a width of 375px, the carousel does only show one slide not 4. I try this:

```
$('.client-carousel').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  arrows: false,
  slide: 'li',
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 375,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    }
  }]
});
```

But this does not change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you decrease a bit **375** like for instance to **350** and try? I believe your issue is there. So, test which is the best value instead to fix it to 375.

Comment: gaetanoM - It is. I set it up to 768 now, and now on iPhone one slide is visible, on iPad 4. That works. Thanks!